# Audio route to speakerphone when using Agora SDK for android

Tags: webrtc, agora.io

Hey can anyone help me with the agora video sdk for android. I'm unable to route the audio from a video call through the speakerphone. The `setEnableSpeakerphone()` returns `0` (success). The default audio routing to speakerphone is also enabled while setting up the `RtcEngine`. Still the audio only comes through the earpiece.

**Edit** : The issue was missing `MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS` permission in the manifest. Check your permissions guys :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the Agora Android Video SDK then you can use the [setDefaultAudioRoutetoSpeakerphone](https://docs.agora.io/en/Voice/API%20Reference/java/classio_1_1agora_1_1rtc_1_1_rtc_engine.html#a8f89328fab2054d74f9dfa7819458866) method

Comment: Yeah, I used this method. Actually the error was the missing `MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS` Permission. Still accepting as this is  actually the correct method.

Comment: Also for anyone looking for dynamically changing the audio route look at the [setEnableSpeakerphone()](https://docs.agora.io/en/Voice/API%20Reference/java/classio_1_1agora_1_1rtc_1_1_rtc_engine.html#a67cf60c4a3f4dade3f49205cd2f044f3) method.